# INSERT INTO Access database with C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd;

            string cmdstring = "INSERT INTO Names (Surname,FName) VALUES('" + txtSurname.Text + "','" + txtFName.Text + "')";

            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, myConnection);
            myConnection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
}
```

I want to add `Surname` and `FName` to access database, but an error has been shown like this `"syntax error"`.
I don't know why.

Comment: What is the exact error you receive? Also you should look into SQL Injection to prevent an attack on your application.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I agree

Comment: @mattytommo - great minds ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 possible reasons your query fails.

1. `Names` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#N).
2. `Surname` or `FName` values which include an apostrophe.

You can avoid the first problem by enclosing the table name in square brackets ... `[Names]`.  But if possible it would be better to choose a different name.

If you switch to a parameter query as others suggested, you can avoid the second problem.  But in that case, still bracket the table name.